# How can I use an image comparison for an automation to know when to run

Tags: automation, autohotkey

I am automating a tedious job, but running into a snag. Using AHK, I am writing a script that looks at x,y coordinates, loops pressing the "Apply" button, moving the cursor to "Me", waits for the "apply" button in a Chrome browser tab, and looks to see if a number changes at x,y coordinates. If there is a change, it runs the rest of the script. Otherwise it continue to look for a change. When the rest of the script is done, it loops back to monitoring again. The script must use AHK code exclusively. As I am running it on a work computer, no add-ons or additional programs (nircmd, Pulover, etc) may be used for functionality of the script.
I cannot figure out why it is not working. I think it has to do with PixelSearch, but I'm just not sure.

I cannot figure out why it is not working. I think it has to do with PixelSearch, but I'm just not sure. Here's what I have:

```
#Persistent
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
CoordMode, Mouse, Screen


;
    Loop
    {
        ; Activate Chrome browser (adjust title as needed)
        IfWinExist, Events - PopCom Analytics - Google Chrome
        {
            WinActivate
        }
        else
        {
            MsgBox, Chrome not found.
            ExitApp
        }

; Click the "Apply" button
        Loop
        {
            ImageSearch, FoundX, FoundY, 0, 0, A_ScreenWidth, A_ScreenHeight, %A_Desktop%\IMAGES\17Apply.PNG
            Sleep, 100
        } until !ErrorLevel
        MouseMove, %foundX%, %foundY%
        MouseClick, left, %foundX%, %foundY%
        Sleep, 500

; Move the cursor to "Me"
        Loop
        {
            ImageSearch, FoundX, FoundY, 0, 0, A_ScreenWidth, A_ScreenHeight, %A_Desktop%\IMAGES\18Me.PNG
            Sleep, 100
        } until !ErrorLevel
        MouseMove, %foundX%, %foundY%
        Sleep, 500
        
;Wait for the "Apply" button to come back
        Loop
        {
            ImageSearch, FoundX, FoundY, 0, 0, A_ScreenWidth, A_ScreenHeight, %A_Desktop%\IMAGES\17Apply.PNG
            Sleep, 100
        } until !ErrorLevel
        MouseMove, %foundX%, %foundY%
        Sleep, 500
        
;********************************************************************************


;Define the coordinates to monitor for change
    X1 := 1530
    Y1 := 385
    X2 := 1620
    Y2 := 405


    ; Capture the content of the specified region
    PixelSearch, ChangeX, ChangeY, X1, Y1, X2, Y2, 0xFFFFFF ; Adjust color and coordinates

    ; Check if a change is detected (adjust threshold and comparison as needed)
    If ErrorLevel = 0
    {
        ; Right Click on "Node"
        Loop
        {
            ImageSearch, FoundX, FoundY, 0, 0, A_ScreenWidth, A_ScreenHeight, %A_Desktop%\IMAGES\RightClick.PNG
            Sleep, 100
        } until !ErrorLevel
        MouseMove, %foundX%, %foundY%
        MouseClick, right, %foundX%, %foundY%, 1
        Sleep, 500

        ;Export All Data
        Loop
        {
            ImageSearch, FoundX, FoundY, 0, 0, A_ScreenWidth, A_ScreenHeight, %A_Desktop%\IMAGES\ExportAllData.PNG
            Sleep, 100
        } until !ErrorLevel
        MouseMove, %foundX%, %foundY%
        MouseClick, left, %foundX%, %foundY%, 1
        Sleep, 250

        ;Export Data
        Loop
        {
            ImageSearch, FoundX, FoundY, 0, 0, A_ScreenWidth, A_ScreenHeight, %A_Desktop%\IMAGES\10ExportData.PNG
            Sleep, 100
        } until !ErrorLevel
        MouseMove, %foundX%, %foundY%
        MouseClick, left, %foundX%, %foundY%, 1
        Sleep, 250

;===================================================================================================================================
        ;Verify Datagrid is open
        Loop
        {
            ImageSearch, FoundX, FoundY, 0, 0, A_ScreenWidth, A_ScreenHeight, %A_Desktop%\IMAGES\datagridExcel.PNG
            Sleep, 100
        } until !ErrorLevel
        MouseMove, %foundX%, %foundY%
        Sleep, 1000
        
        Send, ^q
        
;===================================================================================================================================

        ; TIPA
        Run chrome.exe "https://popcomanalytics.com/Processor/"
        Sleep, 250  

        ;Select One
        Loop
        {
            ImageSearch, FoundX, FoundY, 0, 0, A_ScreenWidth, A_ScreenHeight, %A_Desktop%\IMAGES\12SelectOne.png
            Sleep, 100
        } until !ErrorLevel
        MouseMove, %foundX%, %foundY%
        MouseClick, left, %foundX%, %foundY%
        Sleep, 250

        ; Select "TWyLA (Free)"
        Loop
        {
            ImageSearch, FoundX, FoundY, 0, 0, A_ScreenWidth, A_ScreenHeight, %A_Desktop%\IMAGES\13TWyLAFree.png
            Sleep, 100
        } until !ErrorLevel
        MouseMove, %foundX%, %foundY%
        MouseClick, left, %foundX%, %foundY%
        Sleep, 250

        ; Paste Accounts
        Loop
        {
            ImageSearch, FoundX, FoundY, 0, 0, A_ScreenWidth, A_ScreenHeight, %A_Desktop%\IMAGES\14PasteAccounts.png
            Sleep, 100
        } until !ErrorLevel
        MouseMove, %foundX%, %foundY%
        MouseClick, left, %foundX%, %foundY%
        Sleep, 250
        
        Sleep, 10
        Send ^v
        Sleep, 250

        ; Select "Submit Job"
        Loop
        {
            ImageSearch, FoundX, FoundY, 0, 0, A_ScreenWidth, A_ScreenHeight, %A_Desktop%\IMAGES\15SubmitJob.png
            Sleep, 100
        } until !ErrorLevel
        MouseMove, %foundX%, %foundY%
        MouseClick, left, %foundX%, %foundY%
        Sleep, 250  


;--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Close Events - PopCom Analytics.csv without saving
;--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        SetTitleMatchMode 2 ; Excel-Title can contain
        WinActivate, Events - PopCom Analytics.csv ; go to current Excel-Sheet
        Sleep, 250

        ;Datagrid
        Loop
        {
            ImageSearch, FoundX, FoundY, 0, 0, A_ScreenWidth, A_ScreenHeight, %A_Desktop%\IMAGES\datagridExcel.png
            Sleep, 100
        } until !ErrorLevel
        MouseMove, %foundX%, %foundY%
        Sleep, 250

        Send !{F8} ; call macro-Dialog
        Sleep, 1000
        SendRaw Cxls.xlsm!SheetClose
        Sleep, 250
        Send {return} ; run SheetClose macro
        Sleep, 1000

        WinActivate, Cxls.xlsm
        Sleep, 50
        Send ^{F9} ;Minimize Cxls.xlsm

        Sleep, 1000
        
        ;===========================================================================================
        
        ;Delete the file from the Downloads folder
        
        Send, #{e}
        Sleep, 500
        
        Send, +{Tab}
        Sleep, 500
        
        Send, {Down}
        Sleep, 500
        
        Send, {Down}
        Sleep, 500
        
        Send, {Enter}
        Sleep, 500
        
        Send, {Tab}
        Sleep, 500
        
        Send, {Space}
        Sleep, 500
        
        Send, {Delete}
        Sleep, 500
        
        Send, ^w
        Sleep, 500
        
        ;===========================================================================================        

        if WinExist("Processed - Google Chrome")
        {
            WinActivate
            Sleep, 250
            Send ^{w}
        }
        else
        {

        ; Wait for "Create New Job"
        Loop
        {
            ImageSearch, FoundX, FoundY, 0, 0, A_ScreenWidth, A_ScreenHeight, %A_Desktop%\IMAGES\16CreateNewJob.png
            Sleep, 100
        } until !ErrorLevel
        MouseMove, %foundX%, %foundY%
        Sleep, 250
        Send ^{w}
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ; Sleep to avoid excessive checks
        Sleep, 1000 ; Sleep for 1 second
    }
}

ExitApp
```

Comment: You need to be 100% certain that the location you've set for the pixelsearch to scan will truly have NO white pixels whatsoever. Pixelsearch doesn't compare images; it checks if ANY pixel of the defined color exists in the specified area. If there is even 1 pixel of this color, it will always return 1.

Considering you are looking at a 90x20 block, for the function to return 0, all of these 1800 pixels must be different from 0xFFFFFF.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that so clearly. I'll narrow the field and see what happens.  How does the rest look? :)

Comment: It's hard to say since I can't run the code and validate the flow that's executing. What I can recommend is to use some outputdebug at key points in the script to track the execution flow.